# Where can I extract or copy man executable

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg, man

As our web hosting technician recovered our Linux/Debian squeeze system, I've lost man exetubable. The symptom is:

```
 # ls -l /usr/bin/man
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Oct 11  2011 /usr/bin/man -> ../lib/man-db/man
```

so /usr/bin/man points to /usr/lib/man-db/man

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/man-db/man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug 12  2012 /usr/lib/man-db/man -> ../../bin/man
```

So I've no more hard man binary, but two redundant man symlinks pointing one to another.

My question is, how can I recover the man binary, and from which deb package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man-db package.

Just remove the symlinks, and run:

```
apt-get purge man-db
apt-get install man-db
```

Comment: I've just done those two lines and my "man" works now perfectly. Thank you very much and good Sunday.